# OrientDB .NET driver. Is it still on under development?

Tags: orientdb

We're pondering several options to afford our next project with graph databases.

We're a .NET team and, in spite we like the OrientDB database we have concerns because it seems to me that the .NET driver is not under progress (several years without any commit)

So, are we, as .NET developers on disadvantage?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Only the team would be able to give you a clear answer to that. The Node.js doc is the only that links to actual documentation instead of a GitHub. I'd recommend writing your database code in Node.js, writing your main application code in .NET since you're comfortable with that, and using some kind of interop (such as Edge.js).

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem. Some years ago, there were two drivers for .NET and the one I liked and used was from Innov8tive (the other was from yojimbo87 which I tried but I don'T remember if it worked). Luckily that I downloaded their source code because they removed it from NuGet and GitHub. I asked on OrientDB Web site some year ago and the answer from Luca was that they are working on it, but till today, nothing changed.

So far I'm satisfied with the driver that I have. I am not using it for production but it works for things I use it. I only had to make a small change to select older protocol version with DB version 3.xx because they added handshake and I could not find any documentation on their Website how it works to implement it. With older protocol version selected, the database doesn't use it.

It's really sad that a completed official driver doesn't exist because OrientDB is an amazing database with huge potential. .NET world is also big, so driver for it is really needed.

Tomaz